# ELMAH with IIS6.0 and SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, elmah

On production I have ELMAH configured so that the errors are logged into a SQL Server 2005 database created specially for ELMAH. The sites run on IIS6.0 web server.

ELMAH is able to send emails for the errors, but nothing is getting logged into the SQL Server database.  The connection is a trusted connection and I have

```
<section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah"/> in section group
<errorLog type="Elmah.SqlErrorLog, Elmah" connectionStringName="Elmah.Sql" applicationName="VBCPortal"/> under elmah

<add name="Elmah.Sql" connectionString="Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=ELMAH;Trusted_Connection=True" /> in connectionStrings
```

in my web.config file.

Any idea why the errors are not getting logged into the database?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely cause is the aspnet user account does not have permission to the database.